# fgetcsv() notice: "escape must be a single character" with 'µ'

Tags: php

When I use `fgetcsv()` with `escape` = `µ` like this

```
$filename = 'test.csv';
$handle = fopen($filename, 'r');
$a = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ';', '"', 'µ');
```

php outputs a notice

> Notice: fgetcsv() [function.fgetcsv]:
>   escape must be a single character in myPhpFile.php
>   on line 23

Why?

Comment: Because your escape character isn't a standard ascii character

Answer (score 6, accepted):

µ isn't a standard Ascii character. Which means that PHP sees it as an UTF-8 encoded character which are 16 bits while Ascii is 8 bits. Hence the multiple characters. You should use something else.