# PHP fgetcsv - special seperator

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I'm trying to import a CSV-file with a special seperator (µ). Do you have a suggestion?

```
$_FILE = fopen("file.csv", "r");

while (($data = fgetcsv($_FILE, 1000, "µ")) !== FALSE) {

      echo $data[0].', '.$data[1].'<br>';

}
```

Notice: `fgetcsv()`: delimiter must be a single character in /...

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /...

Many thanks!

Comment: If delimiter is not supported then either use another delimeter or not use `fgetcsv`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fgetcsv() notice: "escape must be a single character" with 'µ'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082068/fgetcsv-notice-escape-must-be-a-single-character-with-%c2%b5)

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
$file = 'file.csv';
$file_handle = fopen($file, 'r');

while (!feof($file_handle)) {

    $line = fgets($file_handle);
    $line = utf8_encode($line);
    $data = explode("µ", $line);

    echo $data[0].', '.$data[1];

}
```

Thanks 4 answer.